# create thread in class

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

Below there is a part of my code:

```
class MyClass 
{
  ...
  HANDLE m_ListenThr;
  DWORD WINAPI ListenThread (LPVOID WorkContext);
  bool CreateListenThreads();
}

bool  MyClass::CreateListenThreads()
{
  ...   
  m_ListenThr = CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyClass::ListenThread,(void*)this, 0,&dwThreadId);

}

DWORD WINAPI MyClass::ListenThread (LPVOID WorkThreadContext) 
{

 MyClass pThis = reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(WorkThreadContext);
 ...
}
```

After compiling i get this error:

> error C3867: 'MyClass::ListenThread': function call missing argument
>   list; use '&MyClass::ListenThread' to create a pointer to member

what i do wrong?

Comment: Did you try writing `&MyClass::ListenThread` as the third parameter to `CreateThread`?

Comment: @imreal yes, i did. The next error is  `error C2664: 'CreateThread' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'DWORD (__stdcall MyClass::* )(LPVOID)' to 'LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the thread function `DWORD WINAPI ListenThread (LPVOID WorkContext);`  as a `static` function of the class:

```
class MyClass 
{
public:
  static DWORD WINAPI ListenThread (LPVOID WorkContext);
}
```

It is not possible to call a member function without an instance of an object. In your case `this` is only a parameter that will be passed as `WorkContext` in your now static function `ListenThread`.

---

As another solution, you could also consider using C++11 `std::bind` so as to create a function object from  that you would pass to CreateThread.

That would go something like this - sorry I have not windows so as to check if this compiles - but it gives you the idea:

```
bool  MyClass::CreateListenThreads()
{
  using std::placeholders;
  std::function <void (void*)> threadFunction = std::bind(&MyClass::ListenThread, *this, _1);
  m_ListenThr = CreateThread(NULL, 0, threadFunction,(void*)this, 0,&dwThreadId);

}
```

but that would sort of use the reference to this twice: as the instance of the class to call the function on, and as a parameter LPVOID WorkContext. Maybe it's awkward in this present case.

Comment: @Hayk Grig as Stephane Roland  said  i did two things: in h files i defined function ListenThread as static: `static DWORD WINAPI ListenThread (LPVOID WorkContext);` and implementation part `CreateThread(NULL, 0, &MyClass::ListenThread,  (void*)this, 0, &dwThreadId);`